# AngularJS: $HTTP.GET is getting cancelled

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

I am trying to use $http service of angularJS but it doesn't seem to work. I have read up online about such an issue but the solutions given doesn't help. I have the following in my controller:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http){    
    var url = http://someurl?name=foo;
    $scope.submitRules = function(){
        $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
              success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.status = status;
                $scope.data = data;
              }).
              error(function(data, status) {
                $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                $scope.status = status;
              });
    };
});
```

I am using this version of angularJS `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js"></script>`

Whenever I try sending the request it shows that the request status is **cancelled**. The URL that I am sending the request to is very well working it just doesn't work form angularJS.
Can someone help?

Comment: This is too vague to understand ... could you give an example?

Comment: I am trying to send some data to my server and want to store it in mysql DB. The data is added to the URL and is sent as http get request. But when I check the developer console in chrome. I see that the request doesn't go through and gets cancelled.

Comment: There could be a lot of causes for that, unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't with your service?

Comment: Yes.. the Url when used directly from the browser is working fine.
when I use jsonp method, it works fine. it looks like CORS.. is there a workaround for this?

Comment: give concrete example

Answer (score 0):

I find all this CORS stuff confusing. But what can I say? I'm a slow learner. The problem you describe may be fixable from the controller, but I think it's better to set things up right at the point of entry. For example:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap']).
    config(function($httpProvider) {

        // Enable CORS
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

        ...
  });
```

Given the code you've provided, this may also work (not tested):

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http, $httpProvider){    
    var url = http://someurl?name=foo;
    $scope.submitRules = function(){

        // Enable CORS
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

        $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
              success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.status = status;
                $scope.data = data;
              }).
              error(function(data, status) {
                $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                $scope.status = status;
              });
    };
});
```

Either way, all the magic happens in these two line:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not CORS, which you can check using chromium with CORS extension, try to set timeout of your request:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http){    
    var url = http://someurl?name=foo;
    $scope.submitRules = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            timeout: 50000
        }).
        success(function(data, status) {
          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.data = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
          $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
        });
    };
});
```

Setting $httpProvider **never** worked for me, it's rather server matter.