# $HTTP.Get is Canceled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, rest

I'm very new to Angular and am try to make a simple "Hello World" webservice call to a simple Rest web service that I've verified returns "Hello World" when you hit it.

I have 3 alerts in the method. I see the "In method" alert and then don't see any of the other alerts. I've attached fiddler and the web service request is never made. I've got to be overlooking something basic here I would think....any ideas on what am I may be missing?

Fiddler shows that the web service call is successful and I can see the results from the Web Service I expect but using Chrome's developer tools shows me that the call to the service is being cancelled by something inside of Angular.

Thanks in advance to any help provided.

```
            (function () {

var app = angular.module("loginApp", ['ngResource'])
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        // Enable CORS
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    });

app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http) {
    this.loginImage = "images/ActiveView_ContentMgm_140x40.png";

    this.loginUser = function () {
        var token = "";
        var loginUrl = "http://ten1.com/services/rest/demoservice.svc/Login";

        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        var result = $http({ method: 'GET', url: loginUrl, params: { userName: this.userName, passWord: this.passWord } })
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
        });

        token = data.Token;
    };

});
```

})();
UPDATE:

Right now I'm clicking the submit button on a login form and just attempting to get back a string so I can verify basic communication with the web service. My goal is to pass the username/password in and get a token back. Here's the form:

```
                    <form ng-submit="loginCtrl.loginUser()" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="border-radius:0px" ng-model="loginCtrl.loginForm.userName" placeholder="Enter username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password </label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" style="border-radius:0px" ng-model="loginCtrl.loginForm.passWord" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Log in</button>
```

Comment: Are you making a get request across domains?  Maybe look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085700/angularjs-http-get-is-getting-cancelled

Comment: I checked that article out, apparently the version of Angular I'm using (1.2.17) no longer supports $httpProvider....call is still getting cancelled by something in angular but the actual web service request is still working

Answer (score 2):

Inject $scope and $http into your controller, not in your `loginUser()` function:

```
 app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http) {
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me part of the way there. Knew it had to be something basic. Now the call is made but it's an error every time even though I hit the Web Service URL manually it functions just fine. Attempting to troubleshoot now. Any thoughts?

Comment: Update: Now the call is made but it's an error every time even though in fiddler the webservice call is a success and I get the data back I'm expecting. So why does it end up in the "error" section when fiddler shows the call worked just fine?

Comment: Not sure, what does console.log(data) show in your error handler?

Comment: It shows that the request status is "cancelled". Almost like something I'm doing initiates the call then calling .success || .error causes the call to be cancelled....

Comment: can you post relevant parts of your HTML?

Comment: reply was to long for comments, adding form to original post.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the service I was hitting was returning a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' " message which would allow the service to complete but would cause Angular to short circuit. I fixed this by adding an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to the Response header in the service.

Links:

[Cross Origin Resource Sharing for c# WCF Restful web service hosted as Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024347/cross-origin-resource-sharing-for-c-sharp-wcf-restful-web-service-hosted-as-wind)

["Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" has no influence in REST Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406350/access-control-allow-origin-has-no-influence-in-rest-web-service)